# How can I make Angular 9 work on Internet Explorer?

Tags: angular, internet-explorer

I'm trying to get my Angular 9 App working on IE 11. Actually, the app is perfectly working on Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Edge but IE is showing a blank page.
I've been trying a lot of stuff :

- I've removed all arrow functions in my code
- Change tsconfig's target from es2015 to es5
- Added and uncommented all IE specifications in polyfill.ts

But same result, my app is still showing blank page whenever I build it and send it on my NGINX server.

I think some of my Node Modules could contain arrow functions, but can't really delete theme.

Is there any way (using Babel for example) of converting my build to a correct ES5 syntax working on IE ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you stated, I would look into Babel [here](https://babeljs.io/setup). I was having a issue in regards to Babel with IE earlier and believe this should work for you

Comment: If this answer was helpful please be sure to accept it.

Comment: How shoud I manage it ? My only js file containing => is my vendor one. Should I use babel on it ? Or on my modules ?

Comment: I would use it on both.